# Chrome showing "Error while loading PDF" in web

Tags: angularjs

I am getting an error in chrome while showing pdf on Web view : "error while loading pdf" many times. I am using object tag / iFrame tag for display but didn't get fix this issue. looking for a helpfull suggestion. Appreciating the answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible scenarios

- The file getting corrupted while downloading using tag / iFrame

better call a http get request to get file and Try creating a blob object with your response

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: blobType });
fileName = 'somename.pdf'
const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
downloadLink.setAttribute("download", fileName);
this.$document[0].body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
this.$document[0].body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

For IE browser specifically :

```
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
```